# Vue Component props value is does not seem on template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Everything is fine in my main.js

```
import User from './components/User.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#user',
    render: h => h(User),
    data() {
        return {
            groups: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getGroups();
    },
    methods: {
        getGroups: function () {
            axios.get('http://vagrant.dev/groups')
                .then(response => this.groups = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
});
```

User.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="user">
        {{groups}} <!-- must be printed but it doesn't seem -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'user',
        props: ['groups']
    }
</script>
```

and index.html

```
<div id="user">
    <user :groups="groups"></user>
</div>
```

[image]

Where is the mistake?

I do not get any errors, but I didn't understand why the value was not printed on the screen

Comment: is there a typo in this.getGroups() and getKurbanGroups? or they are different functions

Comment: sorry, should have been setGroups, thats another func. i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.js` and `index.html` shouldn't mix template in HTML and render function. So your `main.js` should be:

````
```new Vue({
  el: '#user',
  components: { User },
  data() {
      return {
         groups: []
      }
  },
...```
````

4. You shouldn't directly reassign data value because Vue cannot detect property additions and rerender view. You should do it via `Vue.set` or `this.$set` like this:

   `this.$set(this, 'groups', response.data)`

You can read more about how vue reactive in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html and Vue.set API: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: That's not right.This is only if you want declare new property on Vue instance data object, in his case he already declared `groups` as array, so It has observers attached and this property is reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are putting 2 Vue instances on the same template since in your main file you are defining the template as `el: "#user"` which is already controlled by `User.vue`.

In you index.html add a div with `id="app"` and in main.js set `el: "#app"`